# How to reset firmware password on Mac Air?

Tags: mac, firmware, password-recovery

My school put up a firmware password and I need to find a way to reset it. I understand it's illegal but just out of curiosity, is it challenging?

Comment: Your question lacks some details. I a **guessing** that the Mac Air is owned by the school and that you are renting/leasing it? In which case you probably signed a paper stating that you are not allowed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple website](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3554), it's pretty easy if you own the Mac and have a few dollars to spend:

> **Resolution**
>
> Only Apple retail stores or Apple Authorized Service Providers can unlock these computers protected by a firmware password.
>
> If you cannot remember the firmware password for your Mac, schedule a service appointment with either an Apple Retail Store or an Apple Authorized Service Provider.  If you plan to visit an Apple Retail store, please make a reservation at the Genius Bar using http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/ (available in some countries only).

The firmware is hashed and decoding the password would be **very** difficult (as in extremely, massively, near-impossbile) to do yourself, so if your question is "*can I do this easily with free tools on the internet?*" the answer is no.

And just as a side note, even merely *attempting* this on a device you don't own can land you in a courtroom.